Referring to self
I'm not sure what this question should be called, so please edit the post title if desired. Which of the following is correct?

That sounds like a lot of beer to me, who am not a drinker.

That sounds like a lot of beer to me, who is not a drinker.

That sounds like a lot of beer to I, who am not a drinker.


Or is it something else? I know we can just change the phrasing, e.g. "That sounds like a lot of beer to me, since I am not a drinker". But I'd like to stick to the original phrasing to examine the grammar.

"I'd like to stick to the original phrasing to examine the grammar." But you painted yourself into a corner. No good repair. Sounds like a lot of beer to me, not a drinker.

@YosefBaskin It's a corner but there should still be a "best" solution, right? Or are there impossible situations in grammar? Also I don't think your revised version sounds clear.

Related, but I couldn't find a good duplicate, which surprises me.

@tchrist thanks for the reference! The answers to that question seem to suggest that my option 2 is the best. Incidentally, that option seems the worst to my ear...
